"User donot have CREATE FOREIGN CATALOG on ExternalLocation 'stg_container'. SQLSTATE: 42501" pops up when trying to access storage container from DB
I receive the following error "[UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS] Unauthorized access: PERMISSION_DENIED: User does not have CREATE FOREIGN CATALOG on External Location 'stg_container'. SQLSTATE: 42501" when trying to run a pipeline from ADF that invokes databricks notebook. The 'stg_container' is created using "CREATE  EXTERNAL LOCATION" command and has storage credential associated with it.
I can run the databricks notebook manually and it generates output without any error but when i run from the ADF pipeline, the foreign catalog error pops up. I have granted ADF managed identity permission to Databricks. Any solution will be appreciated
